# Split string by whitespace but not within brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, whitespace

I've a string like this `foo bar(5) baz(0, 3)` and need to split it into its parts based on spaces between each. So the result needs to look like this: `['foo', 'bar(5)', 'baz(0, 3)']`.

I tried something like this:

```
var str = 'foo bar(5) baz(0, 3)';
str.split(' '); // => ['foo', 'bar(5)', 'baz(0,', '3)']
```

As you can see the result is not what I expect... Any ideas how to split it correctly? I think it's a turn for the `RegExp`-gurus here...

**Update**

A simple way could be to replace all `,` with `,`:

```
str.replace(/, /g, ',').split(' ');
```

But that doesn't look really pretty to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.match` for this.

```
str.match(/\w+(\(.*?\))?/g)
=> ["foo", "bar(5)", "baz(0, 3)"]
```

Comment: Yeah, looks good :) Thanks so far... I'm of course not a regex-pro, however can we shorten this a bit?

Comment: @yckart I don't see why you want to shorten it ? I would rather try to improve it, maybe something like this `[^()\s]+(\(.*?\))?`

Comment: Awesome :) Saved my day!

Comment: HamZa's answer is good, but needs a slight tweak or it breaks with nested parentheses: `[^()\s]+(\(.*?\)+)?`