# Regex split string by spaces taking into account nested brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I know that this has been asked/answered several times but unfortunately none of the solutions I've tried so far works in my case.
I need to split something like this:

```
contrast(200%) drop-shadow(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px)
```

into this:

```
contrast(200%)
drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5))
```

By following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180821/split-string-by-whitespace-but-not-within-brackets), I'm currently doing this:

```
myString = "contrast(200%) drop-shadow(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px)"
myString.match(/[^\(\s]+(\(.*?\)+)?/g)
```

but this gives me:

```
contrast(200%)
drop-shadow(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)  <== notice the missing second ) here
0px    <== unwanted, should go with previous one
0px    <== unwanted, should go with previous one
10px)  <== unwanted, should go with previous one
```

as the regexp does not capture all closing brackets...

Comment: You cannot match nested brackets in Javascript regex. You will have to parse it using code.

Comment: Please give us sample data which demonstrates _all_ the possible types of inputs and outputs you expect.

Comment: @anubhava: thanks for your answer. So if that is not possible by regex I'll write a function counting brackets. I'll post it when done.

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/uztk5rov/. It splits the string on spaces / tabs (more can be added) that are outside of nested parentheses. Is it what you need?

Comment: @Wiktor: thanks, I was writing my own in the mean time. I'm posting it on answers below.

Comment: I updated my answer to support any whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
function splitBySpaces(string){
    var openBrackets = 0, ret = [], i = 0;
    while (i < string.length){
        if (string.charAt(i) == '(')
            openBrackets++;
        else if (string.charAt(i) == ')')
            openBrackets--;
        else if (string.charAt(i) == " " && openBrackets == 0){
            ret.push(string.substr(0, i));
            string = string.substr(i + 1);
            i = -1;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (string != "") ret.push(string);
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may split a string on spaces/tabs that are outside of nested parentheses using the code below:

```js
function splitOnWhitespaceOutsideBalancedParens() {
  var item = '', result = [], stack = 0, whitespace = /\s/;
  for (var i=0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if ( text[i].match(whitespace) && stack == 0 ) {
        result.push(item);
        item = '';
        continue;
    } else if ( text[i] == '(' ) {
        stack++;
    } else if ( text[i] == ')' ) {
        stack--;
    }
    item += text[i];
  }
  result.push(item);
  return result;
}

var text = "contrast(200%) drop-shadow(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0px 0px 10px)";
console.log(splitOnWhitespaceOutsideBalancedParens(text));
```