# Javascript string split with regex multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split string

`x@x,a,b,c,d(some(other,arg2),p)@yyy` into array

`['x@x','a','b','c','d(some(other,arg2),p)@yyy']`.

The problem i faced is that i cannot split just comma `/\,/g` since members that contains already commas would split also. Any ideas?

Comment: Regex only solution: https://regex101.com/r/VaLYJb/1

Comment: @Wiktor your provided answer link doesn't work for this case (copied from the comments)  -  'cats,(my-foo)-bar,baz' which should return three elements, cats, (my-foo)-bar, and baz. But instead it returns cats(my-foo), -bar, and baz. See my solution instead.  Although that is an accepted answer yet that doesn't mean it should be accepted for all

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman There are others, too. There are lots of such answers. I will add more.

Comment: See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/acvcbsLk/). Adapted from the [Regex split string by spaces taking into account nested brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405230/regex-split-string-by-spaces-taking-into-account-nested-brackets) by mere replacing a space with `,`.